# What can I do to improve application sharing within Microsoft Teams?

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft-teams

Whilst [Microsoft helpfully documents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/stream-classification-in-call-quality-dashboard) the metrics that determine "poor network quality" within calls, there doesn't appear to be any advice on how to affect those metrics; especially with users not on a corporate network.

For example, when I'm working from home, I have a fibre-to-premise broadband connection, which will happily give me connection speeds of 150+ Mbps, with download of 10+ Mbps, and a typical ping of approx 15ms. So nothing too shabby.

However, if I'm using the application sharing in Microsoft Teams, especially with certain apps, like Microsoft Edge, it will constantly moan about poor network quality, and the remote parties struggle to see what I'm sharing.

Looking at the Microsoft guide, it talks specifically about these three metrics:

- Spoiled Tile Percent Total    > 36    - Percentage of tiles that are discarded instead of sent to a remote peer (for example, from the MCU to a viewer). Discarded (or spoiled) tiles might be caused by bandwidth restrictions between client and server.
- AppSharing RDP Tile Processing Latency Average    > 400   - Average latency in milliseconds processing tiles on the RDP Stack at the conferencing server.
- AppSharing Relative OneWay Average    > 1.75  - Average relative one-way delay between the endpoints in seconds for application sharing streams.

So how can I influence and improve those metrics when sharing applications within Teams?

For reference, I'm using a Netgear R6250 router to manage my local network, so could fiddling the MTU size there assist (current 1492), for example?

For the client, it's a [Dell XPS 7590](https://deals.dell.com/en-uk/work/productDetail/7ky5) (so Core™ i7-9750H, 16Gb RAM, 512Gb SSD, Killer™ Wi-Fi 6 AX1650, with a NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 GPU sitting there bored, with most of the work offloading to the Intel UHD Graphics 630 GPU), so I wouldn't expect this to due to a lack of compute power (CPU usage isn't that high when the issues occur; and it spends most of it's life plugged in, with Wi-Fi power saving options disabled)

Comment: If it is *only* Edge, then it might be an issue with capturing that particular application. Does it still do it if you disable hardware acceleration in the Settings? Settings -> System -> Use hardware...

Comment: It does affect other things - Edge just happens to be the one I share the most. Sharing full screen feels like it is affected less, but that might not be statistically significant...

Comment: Fair enough, then for me the suspect is not necessarily your own internet but that of your work. You might have a great internet, but if you have to use a VPN then 50-100 people all sharing one 100Mbps link into an office and doing a video call where it's like 3Mbps in but 10 people all having their data pass through that link can quickly saturate it and cause a problem that way. If no one is using a VPN then my next guess would be GPU and memory limits causing things to be slow on your machine.

Comment: Nope, no VPN here, as I'm going direct over the Internet to M365. (As it happens, if I am in the office, there is _plenty_ of bandwidth, as I can download downloads at gigabit speed :))

Comment: Okay, then the final option is your machine. What specs? Graphics, RAM, CPU, Network card, HDD/SSD and so on would be good. At this point it would be worth editing all this into your question and then the comments can be cleaned up.

Comment: @Mokubai have inlined spec

Comment: Okay, so the machine is more than capable enough as well. Are you connected via wifi or ethernet? If you are on Wifi I would, just to test, try connecting via an ethernet cable for some length of time, even if you have to buy an adaptor. Wifi is a nightmare to diagnose and even "good" connections can have random noise and dropped or repeated packets that can make an otherwise stable connection appear "poor" for these purposes. https://superuser.com/questions/1555726/the-quality-of-the-connection-to-remote-computer-is-poor/1555763#1555763

Comment: @Mokubai how could I measure that to see if it was a felt problem; to avoid a purchase that isn't otherwise needed

Comment: The only real way without buying an adaptor or ethernet cable would be to move the laptop closer to the router, or the wifi router closer to the laptop. The main problem with Wifi is that it is affected by *everything*. From weather, to walls, other people on different networks, other people on the same network, distance, microwave ovens, baby monitors, cordless phones, bluetooth headsets, ground based radio stations, solar flares and (probably) phase of the moon. If your router has 5GHz then using that set of channels might be clearer. Wifi is good for convenience, bad for reliability.

Comment: The laptop is about 12 inches from the router; and going by Netgear WiFi Analytics on my phone, mine is the only WiFi running in the 5GHz band for quite a way...

Comment: https://packetlosstest.com/ Shows no packet loss either

Comment: It might not be actual packet loss, it could be erratic delay due to the wifi protocol, resyncing encryption keys, or just problems in the radios on either side. Leaving the settings at packetlosstest at default might be fine but playing with the various fields can easily produce situations and delays that might be unacceptable for video calls for me yet I have zero problems on my side. I've seen enough problems with Killers supposed "performance" products over the years that I would be suspicious of them, and whenever I hear of problems these days almost universally people are using wifi.